# How to make vstest named pipes work properly in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, permissions, named-pipe

Like so many other people, I'm using Visual Studio to do software development. Now, one of the features that I like is the integration of VSTest into the software.

VSTest relies on named pipes to do communication between the host process (the test process) and the IDE. Unfortunately, there seem to be problems in the communication between the host process and the test runner, which uses named pipes.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17664886/error-debugging-code-in-visual-studio-2012-failed-to-initialize-client-proxy has more information, but since this eventually boils down to an OS/Firewall/Security issue, I decided to ask here.

Now, when you run Visual Studio in Administrator mode, everything suddenly starts to work fine. If you're in a normal user mode on W10, it breaks down. If you enable logging, the following message will be written on the test (client) service:

```
E, 9308, 1, 2016/11/17, 09:53:39.560, 1036805288, vstest.console.exe, TestExecutorServiceClient: Could not connect to test executor service within the available time 60000. Reason:System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: There was no endpoint listening at net.pipe://mylaptop/TestExecutor/10516 that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
```

and the following message will be written on the host (server) service:

```
I, 10516, 1, 2016/11/17, 09:52:39.545, 884887986, vstest.executionengine.exe, TestExecutorService: Starting TestExecutor with command-line arguments /parentProcessId;9308
I, 10516, 1, 2016/11/17, 09:52:39.579, 884968419, vstest.executionengine.exe, TestExecutorService: Created/Started the listening channel. ChannelUri=net.pipe://mylaptop/TestExecutor/10516
```

As you can see, the server reports everything is alive and well, while the client is unable to connect to the uri.

Some things I've tried that have no effect:

- Disable firewall.
- Uninstall virus scanner.
- Mess with the UAC slider.

Ironically, I have a similar system running W10 that works fine. Similar; this is a Dell laptop which was pre-installed, while the other is a hand-build system.

To mitigate the issue, I tried to change the UAC to local administrator, using some policies. While now all the functionality in VS works, it breaks apps with the error `Can't open app with built in administrator`.

Still, it seems to me like a permissions issue... Which made me come here to ask. Suggestions?

Comment: I ran into this issue out of the blue when my vstest project was already working. I removed the test project and went to re-add it, but the SLN file wouldn't let me, so I deleted and re-made the SLN file, re-added the projects, and all was well again. Strange...